# Chai test method is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to get a test working with Mocha/chai.

I have a class myClass.js:

```
export default class Myclass {

    constructor() {}

    sayhello() {
        return 'hello';
    };


}
```

And a test file test.myclass.js:

I am trying to get is to read the method inside the imported class like this:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import {sayhello} from 'path_to_sayhello';

let expect = chai.expect;
let assert = chai.assert;
let should = chai.should();

describe.only('hello world', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        const say = sayhello.add();
        say.should.exist;
    }); 
}
```

The issue here is that it's telling me add is Not a function

Whaqy I'm I doing wrong?

How can I fix this?

Comment: where is the add() defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exporting a class. In your tests you have to initialize an object using the imported class and test the object's method:

```
import Myclass from 'path_to_sayhello';

const instance = new Myclass();
instance.sayhello();
```

Anyway, `hello` string returned from this function will not have `add` method.